# rror: ‘class cv::ml::TrainData’ has no member named ‘getTestSamples’ Mat vdata = tdata->getTestSamples();

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I'm getting this error when using ml , opencv 3.1

```
: error: ‘class cv::ml::TrainData’ has no member named ‘getTestSamples’
 Mat vdata = tdata->getTestSamples();
                    ^
```

what could be the reason for this error ?

here is my ml code :

I have included these in my code

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv::ml;




Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
Ptr<ml::TrainData> tdata = ml::TrainData::loadFromCSV("ear.csv",0,0,1);
tdata->setTrainTestSplitRatio(0.8);

Mat data = tdata->getTrainSamples();
Mat labels = tdata->getTrainResponses();
labels.convertTo(labels, CV_32S); 
svm->train(data,0,labels);

Mat vdata = tdata->getTestSamples();
Mat vlabels = tdata->getTestResponses();
Mat results;
svm->predict(vdata,results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this actually opencv in version 3.1 which you are using?

Looking at the documentation of [TrainData](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d32/classcv_1_1ml_1_1TrainData.html) I actually couldn't see the method you seek in the public interface. There is `getTestSampleIdx` and `getTestSampleWeights` but not the one you wish to call.